# If all array items are hidden show another div in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using ng-repeat on my page. `ng-class` working very well.

```
  <div class="card news" ng-repeat="item in news track by $index" id="{{news.nid}}" ng-init="parentIndex = $index" ng-class="{hidden: '{{getCheck($index)}}' == 'true'}">
      ...

  </div>
```

Now I need, if all items are hidden, show this div:

```
<h3 class="news-empty">No news</h3>
```

Whats the rules? How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another method that checks if all elements are hidden:

```
$scope.everythingIsHidden = function() {
    return $scope.news.every((new, index) => $scope.getCheck(index));
}

$scope.getCheck = function(index) {  // Your getChek function that I suppose it checks if an element is hidden based on index
    //...
}

<h3 class="news-empty" ng-if="everythingIsHidden()">No news</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

TheCog's answer will work. If you want to do this in a more 'Angular' way you're going to need to refactor what you have.

You shouldn't be trying to hide them with a CSS class. ngRepeats have a built in filter syntax. So, you should be filtering them out.

```
<div class="card news" 
     ng-repeat="item in news | filterMethod as results track by $index" 
     id="{{news.nid}}" 
     ng-init="parentIndex = $index" 
 >
<h3 class="news-empty" ng-if="results.length === 0" >No news</h3>
```

The `as results` statement in the repeat will store the filtered array in results. `filterMethod`needs to be an [angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) and it will probably work similarly to your `getCheck($index)` method.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add an [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) to the h3 tag, and aim it at a function you write in your controller that checks if the array is empty, probably by iterating over the same array that's hidden and running getCheck($index) on each.